# How can I render a button object to html?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm hoping that my code will speak for itself. basically, I am trying to insert something like this: `<asp:Button runat="server" Text="Testing" OnClick="ButtonClick" CommandArgument="awesome" CommandName="manage" ID="button7" />` into a table cell. The code you see below is as close as I have gotten. Is there something similar to this?

```
TableRow row = new TableRow();
TableCell manageCell = new TableCell();

Button button = new Button();
button.CommandName = "manage";
button.CommandArgument = "awesome!";
manageCell.Text = button.ToString();


row.Cells.Add(manageCell);

tblRigComponents.Rows.Add(row);
```

Comment: What's the output of the current implementation? What stack are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`TableCell`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.tablecell%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has a `Controls` collection just like a `TableRow`. You can add your `Button` to it and it should render properly:

```
manageCell.Controls.Add(button);
```